# Why is adding an extra 'OR' making a query against a MYSQL View very slow

Tags: mysql, query-performance

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `userListView` `t` 
WHERE (((((((email LIKE '%western millwork%') OR 
(firstName LIKE '%western millwork%')) OR 
(lastName LIKE '%western millwork%')) OR 
(name LIKE '%western millwork%')) OR 
(company LIKE '%western millwork%')) OR 
(companyName LIKE '%western millwork%')) OR 
(visualId LIKE '%western millwork%')) 
AND (active='1') 
ORDER BY `t`.`lastName`, `t`.`firstName` LIMIT 30
```

The query ran fine until I added the line regarding 'companyName'.

Once that happened, it went from about 1 second until 15 - 20 seconds.

I think it's related to how the view is being created? So there's 'company'.'name' and then there's 'companyName' in the 'userListView' which is what I'm querying against.

Here's how the view is being created:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `3form`@`192.168.%.%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `userListView` AS
    (SELECT 
        `user`.`uid` AS `uid`,
        `user`.`active` AS `active`,
        `user`.`email` AS `email`,
        `user`.`fname` AS `firstName`,
        `user`.`lname` AS `lastName`,
        CONCAT(`user`.`fname`, ' ', `user`.`lname`) AS `name`,
        `user`.`company` AS `company`,
        `user`.`cust_id` AS `visualId`,
        `user`.`repid` AS `repId`,
        `user`.`srepid` AS `studioRepId`,
        `user`.`lightartrepid` AS `lightArtRepId`,
        `user`.`exteriorrepid` AS `exteriorRepId`,
        `user`.`nationalrepid` AS `nationalRepId`,
        `user`.`phone` AS `phone`,
        `user`.`phone_ext` AS `phoneExt`,
        `user`.`fax` AS `fax`,
        `user`.`mobile` AS `mobile`,
        `billingAddress`.`label` AS `billingAddressLabel`,
        `billingAddress`.`addr` AS `billingAddressAddr`,
        `billingAddress`.`addr2` AS `billingAddressAddr2`,
        `billingAddress`.`city` AS `billingAddressCity`,
        `billingAddress`.`state` AS `billingAddressState`,
        `billingAddress`.`zip` AS `billingAddressZip`,
        `billingAddress`.`country` AS `billingAddressCountry`,
        `shippingAddress`.`label` AS `shippingAddressLabel`,
        `shippingAddress`.`addr` AS `shippingAddressAddr`,
        `shippingAddress`.`addr2` AS `shippingAddressAddr2`,
        `shippingAddress`.`city` AS `shippingAddressCity`,
        `shippingAddress`.`state` AS `shippingAddressState`,
        `shippingAddress`.`zip` AS `shippingAddressZip`,
        `shippingAddress`.`country` AS `shippingAddressCountry`,
        `branch`.`bid` AS `bid`,
        `branch`.`description` AS `branchDescription`,
        `branch`.`repid` AS `branchRepId`,
        `branch`.`studiorepid` AS `branchStudioRepId`,
        `branch`.`lightartrepid` AS `branchLightArtRepId`,
        `branch`.`exteriorrepid` AS `branchExteriorRepId`,
        `branch`.`nationalrepid` AS `branchNationalRepId`,
        `branchAddress`.`label` AS `branchAddressLabel`,
        `branchAddress`.`addr` AS `branchAddressAddr`,
        `branchAddress`.`addr2` AS `branchAddressAddr2`,
        `branchAddress`.`city` AS `branchAddressCity`,
        `branchAddress`.`state` AS `branchAddressState`,
        `branchAddress`.`zip` AS `branchAddressZip`,
        `branchAddress`.`country` AS `branchAddressCountry`,
        `company`.`cid` AS `cid`,
        `company`.`name` AS `companyName`,
        `company`.`url` AS `companyUrl`,
        `company`.`visual_id` AS `companyVisualId`,
        `company`.`phone` AS `companyPhone`,
        `company`.`fax` AS `companyFax`,
        `companyAddress`.`label` AS `companyAddressLabel`,
        `companyAddress`.`addr` AS `companyAddressAddr`,
        `companyAddress`.`addr2` AS `companyAddressAddr2`,
        `companyAddress`.`city` AS `companyAddressCity`,
        `companyAddress`.`state` AS `companyAddressState`,
        `companyAddress`.`zip` AS `companyAddressZip`,
        `companyAddress`.`country` AS `companyAddressCountry`
    FROM
        ((((((`users` `user`
        LEFT JOIN `useraddr` `billingAddress` ON (((`user`.`uid` = `billingAddress`.`uid`)
            AND (`user`.`billaddr` = (`billingAddress`.`label` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)))))
        LEFT JOIN `useraddr` `shippingAddress` ON (((`user`.`uid` = `shippingAddress`.`uid`)
            AND (`user`.`billaddr` = (`shippingAddress`.`label` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)))))
        LEFT JOIN `branch` ON ((`user`.`bid` = `branch`.`bid`)))
        LEFT JOIN `branch_address` `branchAddress` ON (((`branch`.`bid` = `branchAddress`.`bid`)
            AND (`branch`.`shipto` = (`branchAddress`.`label` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)))))
        LEFT JOIN `company` ON ((`company`.`cid` = `branch`.`cid`)))
        LEFT JOIN `company_address` `companyAddress` ON (((`company`.`cid` = `companyAddress`.`cid`)
            AND (`company`.`billto` = (`companyAddress`.`label` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci))))))
```

The idea is that 'companyName' would take precedent over just 'company' but that hasn't happened yet. Hence, why the original query looks at both.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

**UPDATE**:

Here's the explain:

[image]

Comment: Hm, good luck with that one.

Comment: is the 'where' and 'like' and 'order by' and 'select *' the are delaying the result. Try specifying the 'col names' and get rid of 'order by'

Comment: use Mysql Explain to help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Here's some suggestions: 1. Don't query the view. 2. Use a FULLTEXT index. 3. Select only relevant columns

Comment: @Martin I added a snapshot of the explain. :)

Comment: @Strawberry I would do that, but we're using an omnibox/magic type search where they can enter what they are searching for and it will query all the fields.

Comment: `companyName` doesn't seem to appear/be declared in the View.

Comment: MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: @JasonShultz Why does that matter?

Comment: @Strawberry I see what you're saying. I was focused on #3. If I don't query the view, should I just switch back to joining multiple tables? I was under the assumption that the view would/should be quicker since all the joins are already done?

Comment: Add the EXPLAIN for the query BEFORE the added condition also.

Comment: @Martin That's interesting. If I take 'company' out, and still live 'companyName' in, the explain still shows only 'company'. But, if I take 'company' out and leave 'companyName' in, it's still just as slow.

Comment: While I cannot categorically say that the view will hinder performance, I'm confident that it will do nothing to assist performance.

Comment: anyone know why my question got down voted? I thought I asked it correctly? Was there something wrong with it?

Comment: You did ask the question correctly. Sometimes people give downvotes to questions that present gnarly problems.

Comment: @OllieJones thanks for the response. I was wondering if I did something wrong or not. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query and its underlying view are likely to be slow for several reasons.

1. `column LIKE '%value%'` is the single most effective way to slow down a query. It necessarily must examine every single value in the column, and can't exploit any index lookup.  If you can change some or all these items to `column LIKE 'value%'` you'll see an improvement.
2. `OR` clauses, especially combined with `LIKE '%value%'`, also slow queries. Sometimes the query planner has to make several passes over the result set.
3. You've grouped your `OR` clauses with parentheses, which tells the query planner you don't trust it to make a decision about which parts of the chain of `OR` clauses are most likely to be fastest. Get rid of all those nested parentheses.
4. You're doing a `LIKE` search on the results of a `CONCAT()` operation. That guarantees the above issues can't be optimized away by the query planner.
5. MySQL doesn't have materialized views. The view is reconstructed each time it is used. Views in MySQL are used primarily for clarity, not performance.
6. `SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY something LIMIT small-number` is a classic antipattern in a complex query. It carries out the entire query, then sorts it, then discards most of it.
7. You're using `COLLATE` modifiers on your `JOIN ... ON` clauses. If those are necessary, you're defeating the use of indexes for the `ON` conditions: collations are baked into MySQL indexes. If your `COLLATE` clause overrides the default collation, the index can't be used.
8. But the 'real' problem for the significant slowdown is more insidious.  At first, you were filtering on one table (`users`).  When you added `companyName`, not it needs to also filter on another table in the `VIEW`.  This means it has to keep all the rows from the first table, just in case the `companyName` matches.  A workaround for this is to turn *that* `OR` into a `UNION`.
9. There is no simple speedup for the many problems listed here.

As you try to troubleshoot this, you might want to add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to your select statement, as follows

```
  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE whatever FROM whatever
```

That's because MySQL detects repeated queries, and returns the previous results quickly (in sub-second time) if it can (and if the "Query cache" is turned on).

This kind of wide-angle site search probably should process each major category of data separately. For example, you'll want to do separate single-table queries to pull relevant id values from your `user` and `company` tables, then figure out how to get the relevant data.

Comment: I made this a community wiki entry -- others, please feel free to edit it if you spot other instances of query pessimization.

Comment: Thank you, @OllieJones, that was a great help. I'm going to use your suggestions and see if I can't form my query better. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: (I added more.)  The paragraph on "wide-angle" is the basis of a "fix".

Comment: @OllieJones -- I question whether parentheses ever make a difference in such a context.